# spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I received this error when trying to create tables in spring boot
spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default.Therefore database queries may be rendered during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning.

Reading old post here but to no avail

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Tables are not created after seeing this

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clearer. Anyway, your error has probably nothing to do with the `open-in-view` warning, which is there to let you know that a Hibernate session is open for all the duration of an incoming request. Is there any other error/warning?

Comment: No warning everything is okay but the tables aren’t created

Comment: What is the value of the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` in `application.properties`? It should be `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` if you want to create new tables if they do not exist.

Comment: It’s set to auto but tables aren’t created

Comment: You must set it to update: `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

Comment: I found out  import javax.persistence doesn’t I change javax to Jakarta and it worked